# How do i create objects when working with inheritance?

Tags: java, class, user-interface, super

So, i have the superclass Persona, and subclasses, Estudiante and Docente.
The attributes nombre,cedula,mail are attributes that i wanted to have on Estudiante and Docente because they both have them, but since both Estudiante and Docente are Persona's, i can use inheritage. All these objects have their get/set and tostring methods.
The last code i posted, is an UI that i have. I want to press a button and create an Estudiante, but i cant, because it tells me that im giving more arguments that the ones that i can give, so.. how do i do it? I hope i explained myself well.

I haven't tried anything since i don't really know what to try.
The first time i wrote that code i didnt thought about using this super class Persona, but i was told that i absolutely have to do it like that.

```
public class Estudiante extends Persona{
    private int numero;
    private int semestre;
```

```
public class Docente extends Persona {    
    private int anoingreso;
```

```
public class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private int cedula;
    private String mail;
```

```
private void BotonCrearEstudianteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
        Estudiante=new Estudiante(NombreEstudiante,CedulaEstudiante,MailEstudiante,NumeroEstudiante,SemestreEstudiante);
```

I expect to create an Estudiante in this case, but im going to create Docente's too, and later make teams with many of those two, but i can't because im giving too many arguments as i stated before.

Comment: You need to define a constructor that accepts all of those parameters.  Just having the fields is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside each class you also need to have a constructor- basically what you use to define how one of those objects is created. Like this:

```
public class Persona{
    private String nombre;
    private int cedula;
    private String mail;


    public Estudiante(/*Insert the parameters you need, but do not call them by the same thing as your instance variables above*/){
       /*this block will execute when you create an Estudiante object*/
    }
}
```

But when you get to the *child* classes (i.e. Estudiante and Docente), you can use the `super()` method inside the constructor, which on call will run the parent class' constructor.

[Give this a read too.](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_constructors.asp)